# Can't save Category Display Mode in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree

I can't save Display Mode setting when updating a category in `Catalog > Category` session.

Only Products is working. Another 2 options are not being saved.

> Is there an issue about it? How to solve?

Magento 1.9.3.4 on PHP 7

Comment: Please delete var/ folder of Magento root and check again.

Comment: Deleted. No effect. Var folder was empty. I'm using Redis.